# PHP Unix Time missing zeros

Tags: php, date, time

Okay so I have the following formula, but for some reason the minutes I can't ever tell if it is 5 minutes or 50 minutes cause it either doesn't show a zero or drops a zero. So when I echo "$h:$m"; It shows as 7:5 for example. Any ideas?

```
    $now = time();
    $diff = $now - $phpdate;
    $w = $diff / 86400 / 7;
    $d = $diff / 86400 % 7;
    $h = $diff / 3600 % 24;
    $m = $diff / 60 % 60; 
    $s = $diff % 60;

    $PD = "$h:$m";
```

Comment: Use `sprintf()` or `date()`.

Comment: If you want calculate diff between datetimes you can use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php and many other (see this link)

Comment: The time is stored as unix time in the database, not as datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_pad` and can add `0` string in front of hour and minute if those are in single digit. You can do something like this -

```
$now = time();
$diff = $now - 30939007;
$w = $diff / 86400 / 7;
$d = $diff / 86400 % 7;
$h = $diff / 3600 % 24;
$m = $diff / 60 % 60; 
$s = $diff % 60;

// add 0 to left if string is single chars
if (strlen($h) == 1) {
  $h = str_pad($h, '2', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
if (strlen($m) == 1) {
 $m = str_pad($m, '2', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$PD = "$h:$m";
echo $PD;
```

[Check str_pad documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Hope this will help you (y).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid other overhead since all you need is a simple padding, you could pad the ones requiring length of two (padding with '0' of course, but only if the string isn't already two in character length):

```
$m = str_pad($m, '2', '0');
$s = str_pad($s, '2', '0');
```